# How to remove the brightness region in the image?

Tags: algorithm, image-processing, machine-learning

I have a foreground region that represents by gray color. The background is the black color. In the edge of the foreground, I have some isolate regions which shows by brightness region as a figure. Could you suggest to me the algorithm to assign to brightness region to the background? It means the result only has two classes and the isolate region resulting in the background region. I have tried graph-cut but it assigns the brightness region to the foreground. Thanks

Machine learning allows here because I also have some patterns of the brightness region 
[image]

Comment: I would use thresholding ... if  pixel intensity is above some value its the bright pixel ...

Comment: Your explanations are unclear. Can you show the expected result ?

Comment: I think oop want to remove some artifact in the boundary. Threshold is one option but it is sensitive to threshold value.

Comment: Yes. I want to remove the brightness region in the boundary. Its intensity is various so I cannot use threshold in here

Comment: @Jame bright usually means above average so thresholds should work. Especially for image like yours. (Thresholding does not mean compare to some single color rather deciding if the brightness is bigger or smaller than it so varying colors are not a problem unless by varying you mean any brightness even black ...) Anyway if you got just few valid colors you can also distinct if pixel has color from list of valid colors or not ...